# How to run a structured query

Tags: marklogic

This feels like it should be easy, but the easy stuff isn't working, so here goes:

I'm trying to write a REST API extension (using SJS) that will accept a structured query, do a little manipulation on part of it, and then run it. The manipulation of the incoming query was simple enough, but I'm having trouble with the result. Basic question -- if you've got a structured query as a JS object, how do you run it? I want to get JSON as a result.

JSearch seemed like the right approach, but doesn't seem willing to accept what I have to give it.

This works:

```js
const jsearch = require('/MarkLogic/jsearch.sjs');
jsearch.documents()
  .where(cts.parse("cat"))
  .result()
```

This doesn't:

```js
let query = 
  {
    "wordQuery": {
      "text": [ "cat" ], 
      "options": [ "lang=en" ]
    }
  };
jsearch.documents()
  .where(query)
  .result()
```

That results in

> JSEARCH-INVALARGS: fn.error(null, "JSEARCH-INVALARGS", msg); -- Invalid arguments: where() takes one or an array of cts.query() objects

`query` is a JS object. I tried turning it into a Node, but got the same result. How do I use a JS object that contains a structured query?

Comment: Be careful: `cts.parse` returns a `cts.query`, and not a so-called structured query..

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you deserialize the JSON query first with the cts.query() constructor, as in `.where(cts.query(jsonQuery))`

In general, passing the query as the JSON serialization of a cts.query and manipulating the JSON structure in the main module seems like the right approach.

The cts.query vocabulary is a superset of the structured query vocabulary.  Also, deserialization of a cts.query is faster than transformation of the JSON representation of a Search API query.

In case it's useful to someone else looking at this exchange, one way to serialize a cts.query to JSON is with xdmp.toJSON() as in `xdmp.toJSON(cts.wordQuery(['cat'], ['lang=en']))`

Hoping that helps,

Comment: There might be a small overlap, but cts.query vocab is no superset, nor a subset of structured queries. They look similar, and have similar purpose, but the syntax is different in all kinds of subtle ways.

Comment: @ehennum I should be able round-trip the serialization, right? `cts.query(xdmp.toJSON(cts.wordQuery(['cat'], ['lang=en'])))` gives me nothing.

Comment: @DaveCassel, cts.query() appears to require a root node instead of a document node.  At least, the following works for me:  `cts.query(xdmp.toJSON(cts.wordQuery(['cat'], ['lang=en'])).root)`